# Validação do APK na Google

Tags: android, xamarin, oauth2

Tenho um `app` que preciso validar a integridade dos dados do mesmo. Para isso, preciso que o `google` me diga se aquele aplicativo foi assinado por ele ou não.
Mas pra isso funcionar, preciso que ele me gere um `token` para validação.

isso é possível?

Answer (score 0):

Diego, tenho quase certeza que o `Google Play` Console não gera o `token`, inclusive para as demais atualização, a Google sempre vai pedir que o `app` seja finalizado com a mesma chave. Quando se programa com o `Android Studio` ele dá a possibilidade de você criar quando está finalizando para a publicação.

Comment: você está se referindo na hora de assinar o app, certo?

Comment: Exaatamente, na hora de mandar ele precisa ter essa assinatura.

Comment: Entendi... Então, eu faço isso, é requisito da GooglePlay, mas o que quero, é exatamente isso: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33093617/google-authentication-with-a-backend-server-required-scopes
Mas para xamarin, com classes em C# e não estou achando em lugar nenhum.